# JSON.serialize alternative which support more objects like HttpRequest or Schema Describes

Tags: apex, json, serialization

Often I need a easy and robust way to convert huge nested data structures into an string. Mostly for dumps, logs and debug. JSON.serializePretty() comes close but does not support all Object types like HttpRequest or Schema describe results and others.

Has anyone seen or written a APEX serializer which supports more types than JSON?

Comment: There is always `string.valueOf()` as a fallback. However, it doesn't represent data for serialization/deserialization. Without greater reflection support I'm not sure how you would find the required information about a random object.

Comment: @Daniel you are right about the poor reflection-suppot. The problem is that the schema class applies to SObjects not Object. JSON.serialize() fails to my knowledge only on non-SObjects. First it would be required to collect a list of all known unsupported types. Then we could write at least a wrapper-method to capture unsupported types on top-level. e.g. for HttpRequest we could write some custom dump. But for nested unsupported types, I have no idea.